# Как сделать свой url в произвольном типе поста Wordpress c Cherry Framework?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, seo

У меня стоит простая задача, поменять url c vikatorr.ru/portfolio-view/aisuma/ на url такого вида vikatorr.ru/aisuma/ в произвольных типах записи. Однако я не смог найти в документации, как это настроить при помощи PHP.Подскажите, как это сделать для всего типа поста.
В результате 404 http://vikatorr.ru/banksalen/

```
/* Portfolio */
function my_post_type_portfolio() {
    register_post_type( 'portfolio',
        array( 
                'label'             => theme_locals("portfolio"),
                'singular_label'    => theme_locals("portfolio"),
                '_builtin'          => false,
                'public'            => true, 
                'show_ui'           => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                'hierarchical'      => true,
                'capability_type'   => 'page',
                'menu_icon'         => get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/images/icon_portfolio.png',
                'rewrite'           => FALSE,
                'supports' => array(
                        'title',
                        'editor',
                        'thumbnail',
                        'excerpt',
                        'custom-fields',
                        'comments')
                    ) 
                );
    register_taxonomy('portfolio_category', 'portfolio', array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => theme_locals("categories"), 'singular_name' => theme_locals("category"), "rewrite" => true, "query_var" => true));
    register_taxonomy('portfolio_tag', 'portfolio', array('hierarchical' => false, 'label' => theme_locals("tags"), 'singular_name' => theme_locals("tag"), 'rewrite' => true, 'query_var' => true));
}
add_action('init', 'my_post_type_portfolio');

global $wp_rewrite;
$projects_structure = '/%portfolio%/';
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%portfolio%", '([^/]+)', "\portfolio=");
$wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('portfolio', $projects_structure, True);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем разбирался я долго, но успешно. Все это для Cherry Framework.

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts','exclude_post');
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','portfolio_rewrite_rules' );
add_filter( 'query_vars','my_insert_query_vars' );
add_action( 'wp_loaded','my_flush_rules' );

// Сбиваем правила flush_rules(), если наших еще нет в списке (операция ресурсоемкая, поэтому не стоит ее делать каждый раз)
function my_flush_rules(){
 $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );

 // достаточно проверить, есть ли в списке хотя бы одно из наших правил
 if ( ! isset( $rules['meetings/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$'] ) ) {
 global $wp_rewrite;
 $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
 }
}

// добавляем наши правила
function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules )
{
 $newrules = array();
 //$newrules['banksalen/bryllyp/?$']='index.php?portfolio=banksalenbryllyp';
 //$newrules['(aisuma|cafe-bagle|tavern-vertshus|banksalen|den-gode-nabo|grenaderen-vertshus|gronn-pepper|frati-catering|sushi-bar|gjest-baardsen|havfruen-selskapslokaler|mormors-stue|selskapslokale|festsalen|bari-cafe-og-bar|havfruen|bryggen-asian|frati)/?$']='index.php?portfolio=$matches[1]';
 $newrules['forum/([^/]*)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?topic=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]';
 $newrules['forum/([^/]*)/([0-9]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?forum=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
 $newrules['forum/([^/]*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?topic=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]';
 $newrules['forum/([^/]*)/(.*)/?$'] = 'index.php?topic=$matches[2]';
 $newrules['forum/([^/]*)/?$'] = 'index.php?forum=$matches[1]';
 $newrules['(library|books|articles|tools|projects|diagrams)/([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
 $newrules['(library|books|articles|tools|projects|diagrams)/?$'] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]';
 $newrules['([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?&paged=$matches[1]';
 $newrules['meetings/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$'] = 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]&post_type=event';

 return $newrules + $rules; // так оно добавляет наши правила к уже существующим, а еще мы можем тупо убрать все и вернуть только свой список, сделав return $newrules;
}

function portfolio_rewrite_rules( $rules )
{
 $newrules = array();
 $newrules['banksalen/banksalen-i-trondheim/?$']='index.php?portfolio=banksalen-i-trondheim';
 $newrules['banksalen/konferansesenter-i-trondheim/?$']='index.php?portfolio=konferansesenter-i-trondheim';
 $newrules['banksalen/skreddersy-ditt-selskap/?$'] = 'index.php?portfolio=skreddersy-ditt-selskap';
 $newrules['banksalen/forretningsmiddag/?$']='index.php?portfolio=forretningsmiddag';
 $newrules['banksalen/julebord-banksalen-festlokaler-julebord-for-firma-trondheim/?$']='index.php?portfolio=julebord-banksalen-festlokaler-julebord-for-firma-trondheim';
 $newrules['banksalen/forretningsmiddag/?$']='index.php?portfolio=forretningsmiddag';
 $newrules['banksalen/bryllyp/?$']='index.php?portfolio=bryllyp';
 $newrules['('.portfolio_rerule().')'.'/?$']='index.php?portfolio=$matches[1]';
 return $newrules + $rules; 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте через `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?portfolio-view=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?portfolio-view=$1
```

Comment: Не похоже, я думаю все таки стоит это делать при помощи темы.

Comment: @VasilyukDmitry дайте мне ваш .htaccess

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: @VasilyukDmitry обновил ответ