# Как убрать знак вопроса из ссылки

Tags: php, .htaccess, wordpress, url, ссылки

Есть ссылка:

`brovkoantiques.ru/auction/?ult_auc_id=454` нужно привести к виду:       `brovkoantiques.ru/auction/ult_auc_id=454` Подскажите  как реализовать?
Если я перепишу правило, то при переходе по ссылке у меня будет ошибка 404. Как убрать само добавление этого вопроса при формировании ссылки?

Comment: Вы столько тегов к вопросу поставили ... Если речь про php то `$url=str_replace('?','',$url)` Если нет - то поправьте вопрос, поставьте правильные теги

Answer (score 4):

Потребуется добавить в файл .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^auction/ult_auc_id=([0-9]+)$ auction/?ult_auc_id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Ребят  в Wordpress это делается на уровне функций. Так не сработает. Судя по ссылке у него произвольный тип поста, а не страница.

Answer (score 2):

Для этих целей есть специальный модуль, который называется "mod_rewrite". Он позволяет «переписывывать урлы», то есть, преобразовывать их «на лету» по правилам, которые Вы ему опишите.
Это очень мощный инструмент, если в нём разобраться, то можно делать, что душе угодно. [Полезная статья на хабре.](http://habrahabr.ru/company/sprinthost/blog/129560/) Надеюсь она поможет.

Answer (score 2):

Приветствую. На уровне Wordpress существуют свои правила, которые можно переписать без больших трудозатрат можно используя функции. 
Вот аналог из моего вопроса "[Как сделать свой url в произвольном типе поста Wordpress c Cherry Framework?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464278/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-url-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-wordpress-c-cherry-framework)". Он должен сработать при любой конфигурации темы. Перед проверкой не забудь поставить url вида ?p=1048 в настройкой и вернуть обратно на кастомные. Тогда 404 должна исчезнуть. Регулярку возьми по аналогии из ответа @Plush.